# Phisycal ressources for spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, virtualization

I trying to learn `spark` to implement one of our algorithms to increase the execution time. I downloaded a pre-compiled version on my local machine to run it in a local mode and I enjoyed creating some toy apps.

Next step is to use the cluster mode ( `standalone` one at this level).

I found a lot of amazing tutorials talking about how to configure the cluster and the difference between local and cluster modes and this is really clear ( I will be back here if I had troubles with that ).

My question for now is:

**What physical infrastructure to use for spark cluster?**

No downvotes please, I will explain: For now, we have 2 dedicated server with `32Go of RAM` and `8 CPUS` each one.

Now I am asking:

> What is the best way to fully exploit this resources with spark?
>
> Which is better:
>
> - Use a virtualization ( ESXI / Proxmox ) in order to create virtual machines which will be my cluster nodes?
> - just use the two servers and create a 2-noded cluster?

Comment: Are you sure you want to *__increase__ the execution time*? :)

Comment: Regarding the question. Even if you assume that visualization could be a good choice there is not much you can share here. 32GB and 8 cores is not much from the beginning.

Comment: Actually, we are using python, so I think YES even with 8CPUs and 32Go spark will be much better. Anyway, I want a POC, if it works we will scale ;)

Comment: I don't criticize but my point is there is not much to share. You need JVM worker, JVM executor and Python executors on each machine. Each of these requires some share of the resources. Regarding performance you wouldn't expect to much. On a single machine with similar configuration as you describe you can do much better with pure Python in a single thread. And even better using with smart tools like joblib or dask.

Comment: As @zero323 said there is not much to share, but that's a starting point and the main interest I see here is that you can start developing your code and think about going for a larger cluster later on, you app will scale. It also very much depend where your data are coming from (same machines?).